# Get the returning url after POST in android

Tags: java, android, apache, httpclient

I have to post some data to an url, here's my code. After this server must redirect me to a new URL, but hpw do i get it in android?

```
public void postData() {

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/script.php");

    try {

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "data"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));


        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
}
```

Comment: Please specify whether you need to sent data to the server or get data from the server....

Comment: First of all i send data to the server via a POST request, then after this server must redirect me to a new page, and i need to get this page url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the url in php by using $_server and echo that string.

Instead of using

> HttpResponse response =
>   httpclient.execute(httppost);

use the following code

```
 ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler(); 
  String ResponseBody = httpClient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
```

Now the response body string contains the url you echo from the php server